# HTML5 Scoped attribute on <style> elements and CSS animations

Tags: css, html, css-animations

As I [understand](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped), the "scoped" attribute on a `<style>` element in the body of an HTML5 document is supposed to limit the scope within that parent element.

I'm not actually in need of the scoping effect, but I do like that adding this attribute makes `<style>` elements in the body valid HTML5.

However, at least on Firefox, applying it seems to make animations fail. Firefox 42 without the `scoped` attribute, annoyingly, works, forcing the choice between something that works, and something that is valid. Is this a browser bug/limitation? Or is it something I've misunderstood about the spec? Both scoped and unscoped versions work in Chromium.

Here's demo code, pasted here for reference, but [see live demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z219c1v/4/).

```
<div>
    <!-- Without "scoped" attribute, it works -->
    <style>
        @keyframes anim2 {0% {color:black;} 100% { color:red;} }
        div.unscoped {animation-name:anim2; animation-duration:1s; animation-iteration-count:infinite;}
    </style>
    <!-- Same but with scoped, does not work -->
    <style scoped>
        @keyframes anim {0% {color:black;} 100% { color:red;} }
        div.scoped {animation-name:anim; animation-duration:1s; animation-iteration-count:infinite;}
    </style>
   <!-- Two demo divs -->
   <div class="unscoped">works, hey I miss &lt;blink&gt;</div>
   <div class='scoped'>does not work in Firefox 42/Ubuntu (but does work in Chromium) :-(</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Support for scoped stylesheets is abysmal at the moment. It's not ready for production use.

Comment: What Boltclock is saying is that your demo works in Chrome because Chrome doesn't support `scoped`, so it treats both style elements the same. Anyway, a solution (for Firefox that is) is to move the `@keyframe` blocks to the global stylesheet; only keep the local div styles in the scoped style elements. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6z219c1v/5/ I have no idea why this works though; if it's a flaw in Firefox that it can't find the `@keyframe`s or something official, so I'm not posting it as an answer.